# Why can clone array without type cast?

Tags: java, arrays, clone

Found that I can do following:

```
package test.java.lang;
import java.util.Arrays;

    public class Tester_ArrayCloning_01 {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            double[] vals1 = {1.2, 2.3, 3.4, 4.5};
            double[] vals2;

            // vals2 = (double[])vals1.clone(); // was thinking should do so
            vals2 = vals1.clone(); // but happened can do so

            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(vals2));
        }

    }
```

Why? When it was introduced?

Comment: Bear in mind that this is a shallow clone not a deep clone. Not sure that I understand the question `Why?` Why does the language support this? Is that the question?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [section 10.7 of the JLS, array members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.7):

> The members of an array type are all of the following:
>
> ...
>
> - The public method `clone`, which overrides the method of the same name in class Object and throws no checked exceptions. The return type of the clone method of an array type T[] is T[].

The [same section in the third edition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/arrays.html#10.7) has the same content.

The [second edition](http://titanium.cs.berkeley.edu/doc/java-langspec-2.0.pdf) says that array types override `clone()`, but at that point there was no return type covariance, so they couldn't have done so returning `T[]`.

So basically it was introduced in 1.5.

Answer (score 3):

The return type of the method `clone` for an array of type `T[]` is `T[]`. Since `Object.clone()` return `Object` such definition requires covariant return types, that were introduced in Java 5.

[Previously](http://csclub.uwaterloo.ca/~mmmulani/langspec-2.0/arrays.doc.html), `clone` was defined to return `Object`. That is particularly the kind of issues for what covariant return types are good for,

Answer (score 3):

Java 5 introduced **covariant return types**, which allows any code (including your own) to take advantage of them. The general feature allows an overriding method to declare a return type that is a subtype of the original return type. Note that the declared type of your variable must be right for this to work. For example, the following doesn't compile:

```
Object vals1 = {1.2, 2.3, 3.4, 4.5};
double[] vals2;
vals2 = vals1.clone();
```